# Should I use a semicolon or a colon to introduce a question at the end of a sentence?

Tags: punctuation, questions, semicolons, colons

Which of the following is punctuated correctly?

> - My question for you is: how do I do that?
> - My question for you is; how do I do that?

Or should it be something different altogether?

Answer (score 3):

Colon works. Comma would also work "My question is, how do I do that? Semicolon is used for something else entirely.

Comment: Exactly. Colons, semicolons, and commas (among others) are contrasted nicely [by Lewis Thomas](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/punctuation.html).